# IBM Watson Assistant in Flutter: How to show options?

Tags: flutter, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I created an IBM Watson Assistant chatbot, and a flutter app. I'm using the package watson_assistant_v2. My bot returns response options. How do I show them visually?

I'm using the package example and I didn't find anything about it.

In Watson Assistant, defining the options:

[image: Assistant responds]

Preview, showing the options:

[image: Assistant preview]

My app, not showing options:

[image: On app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response options are encoded in the JSON structure which Watson Assistant returns. You can see [the options here as part of the API definition](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2#messagestateless). The documentation for Watson Assistant discusses [receiving an option response](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-dialog-responses#receiving-an-option-response) as part of [implementing option responses](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-dialog-responses#api-dialog-option-example).

You need to decode the response and show the options as clickable UI element.

Comment: Oh yes, it worked for me, reading the documentation is always the right way.
Thanks! :D