# How to add various numbers of button to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Basically, my question is similar to this one:[IBM Watson Assistant in Flutter: How to show options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64667601/ibm-watson-assistant-in-flutter-how-to-show-options)

There is only one answer, telling me to decode the response and show the options as clickable UI elements. **I already know how to decode it, but how to make them clickable as a button?** Like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3r3Y.png)

I am not familiar with RecyclerView enough, maybe some method could do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can add onClickListener to views so if you are using textviews for showing options you can add click listener like this in your RecyclerView Adapter class

```
textViews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //YOUR CODE
        }
    });
```